# Redirect hostname/endpoint to api.hostname/endpoint in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have my api built with this pattern: api.hostname/endpoint.
However there is a plugin to my app that uses hostname/endpoint pattern.
I would like to solve it on the backend side by adding redirection to api.hostname/endpoint.

I tried to experiment with adding urls or paths to urlpatterns, but it didn't help me.
How can I achieve it? Any ideas?

Regards,
Maciej.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib`

```
import urllib.parse

url = "https://hostname/endpoint"
split_url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
result = f"{split_url.scheme}://api.{split_url.hostname}/{split_url.endpoint}"

print(result)
>> "https://api.hostname/endpoint"
```

Comment: But how can I tell django to look under second url if someone reaches first one?

Comment: try this: `from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView` `path("<endpoint>", RedirectView.as_view(url=your_redirect_url))`